# Python declare empty record array

Tags: python, arrays

I want to declare an empty record array like this:

```
kneePointsOnAxis = np.recarray((3,), dtype=[(int, int, int)])
```

However, it gives me and error:

```
TypeError: data type not understood
```

At the end I would like my record array to look like this:

```
[(7.0, 0.0, 21.0) (16.0, 0.0, 6.0) (45.0, 0.0, 1.0)]
```

I read this array from the CSV file without any problem. However, I would like to create and edit it manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
kneePointsOnAxis = np.recarray((3,),dtype=[('x',int), ('y', int), ('z',int)])
```

Comment: thanks for the answer it works. Can I append one more question? I have another array like this - `>>> print x [(7.0, 0.0, 7.0) (16.0, 0.0, 1.0)]` Now I would like to add elements as - `kneePointsOnAxis.append((0.,x[i][1],x[i][2]))`. I changed the type to float. However it gives me an error `AttributeError: record array has no attribute append`. What should I do?